# Решение линейных уравнений методом Гаусса

Tags: c++

Имеется код методом Гаусса:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m;
    //создаем массив
    cout << "Number of equations: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Number of variables: ";
    cin >> m;
    m += 1;
    float **matrix = new float *[n];
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        matrix[i] = new float[m];

    //инициализируем

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)

        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << " Element " << "[" << i + 1 << " , " << j + 1 << "]: ";

            cin >> matrix[i][j];
        }

    //выводим массив
    cout << "matrix: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    //Метод Гаусса
    //Прямой ход, приведение к верхнетреугольному виду
    float  tmp;
    int k;
    float *xx = new float[m];

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp = matrix[i][i];
        for (j = n; j >= i; j--)
            matrix[i][j] /= tmp;
        for (j = i + 1; j<n; j++)
        {
            tmp = matrix[j][i];
            for (k = n; k >= i; k--)
                matrix[j][k] -= tmp*matrix[i][k];
        }
    }
    /*обратный ход*/
    xx[n - 1] = matrix[n - 1][n];
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        xx[i] = matrix[i][n];
        for (j = i + 1; j<n; j++) xx[i] -= matrix[i][j] * xx[j];
    }

    //Выводим решения
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << xx[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    delete[] matrix;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Он хорошо работает, когда число уравнений равно числу неизвестных. Как можно сделать, чтобы можно было решать, число уравнений больше, чем число неизвестных. 
Например:

```
  2,0,0,2=576
    7,1,0,0=1570
    0,0,1,1=87
    5,0,1,0=1011
    1,1,2,0=360
    2,1,0,1=646
    1,0,1,1=289
    0,2,1,0=313

Ответ: х1=202,х2=156,х3=1,х4=86.
```

Помогите, доделать, пожалуйста

Comment: Скажите, если подставить ваши ответы в четвертое, например, уравнение? 5*202+1*1 равно 7?

Comment: исправил, были ответы по модулю

Comment: ну тогда выбирайте любые N линейно независимых. А лучше используйте расширенный алгоритм, получили все 0 - удаляйте строку как бесполезную.

Comment: Расширенный алгоритм кого?